# MVC4 Validation happens after submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-javascript

I have some issues with my MVC4 applications - the form validation happens only after submit.

I want the form to be validated before submission.
This is (part) of my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    Html.EnableClientValidation();
    Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript();
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Offer</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HotelName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HotelName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HotelName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocationName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LocationName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LocationName)
     </div>
```

I also have in my web.config

```
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

And these are all the scripts included in my page

```
    <script type="text/javascript" length="7" src="/Scripts/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.js?cdv=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" length="7" src="/Scripts/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js?cdv=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" length="7" src="/Scripts/jquery/jquery.cookies.js?cdv=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" length="7" src="/Scripts/language.js?cdv=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqueryval/jquery.validate.js?cdv=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqueryval/jquery.validate.min.js?cdv=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqueryval/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js?cdv=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqueryval/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js?cdv=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js?cdv=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js?cdv=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/file-upload/jquery.fileupload.js?cdv=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/file-upload/jquery.fileupload-process.js?cdv=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/file-upload/jquery.fileupload-main.js?cdv=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/file-upload/jquery.fileupload-validate.js?cdv=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/file-upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js?cdv=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.jcrop.min.js?cdv=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/imagemodel.js?cdv=1">
```

As far as I know the validation is done with jquery unobtrusive.
The weird thing is that if I manually run $("form").valid() from console, it returns true, but if I have the "required" attribute on the  then $("form").valid() triggers correctly.

Is there a way to add the "required" attribute to the neccesary inputs? Or perhaps there is another way to do client side validation.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using view model? Do they have required attributes?

Comment: It all depends on what validation you have on your model. if you are using `DataAnnotaions` you will have to add attribues to your model, FluentValidation will require a different class

Comment: Yes, I think the model has the required attributes.                       `[Required]
[DisplayName("Hotel")]
public string HotelName { get; set; }` I don't have experience with MVC, so if there's something wrong I'm more than willing to acknowledge and fix

Comment: I noticed that my model properties do not have data-val and data-val-required attributes added for strings. So it seems this is the problem, if I manually add them to the DOM page it works, but I don't know how to make mvc add them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have come to, is to create an extension for the HtmlHelper class that creates custom validated controls, where the validation attributes are added to the generated HTML.

```
  public static MvcHtmlString ValidatedTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> attributes)
    {
        var message = GetMessage(htmlHelper, expression);
        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, new Dictionary<string, object>(attributes)
            {
                { "data-val", "true" },
                { "data-val-required", message ?? "Must not be empty"},
            });
    }

 private static string GetMessage<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        PropertyInfo[] props = metadata.ContainerType.GetProperties();

        string message = null;
        var info = props.First(prop => prop.Name == metadata.PropertyName);
        var attribute = info.GetCustomAttribute(typeof (RequiredAttribute)) as RequiredAttribute;
        if (attribute != null)
        {
            message = attribute.ErrorMessage;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                var resource = attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType;
                var resourceName = attribute.ErrorMessageResourceName;

                if (resource == null || resourceName == null)
                    return null;

                message = new ResourceManager(resource).GetString(resourceName);
            }
        }

        return message;
    }
```